# How do I fix migrations so rake db:migrate works again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

The original issue is that some migration files were originally run on a machine (like production).  Later, a few migrations were somehow deleted and could not be recovered.

So, to get a new machine up and running with the app, I had to manually recreate the missing migrations.

Thus, a machine that already performed the deleted migrations is now throwing these errors.

`PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "some_relation" already exists`

I can't just `db:reset` the db on production because I can't lose that data.

When I run, `rake db:test:prepare` something like this shows up:

```
You have 4 pending migrations:
  20130112203055 CreateSomeTable
  20130113180203 AddSomeColumnToTable
  20130113204017 ChangeSomeOtherColumns
  20130311203729 CreateAnotherTable
Run `rake db:migrate` to update your database then try again.
```

Obviously, running `db:migrate` will give the PG::Error as stated above.  The problem is the schema changes have already been completed via the deleted migrations.  The above 'pending' migrations had to be recreated after the fact.

Is there a way to fix this so `db:migrate` works again?

Comment: In the migration that creates `"some_relation"`, can you just check to see if that table already exists? Do some conditional statements to only create the tables/indices/etc if they haven't already been created?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following,

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20121031XXXXXXXX
rake db:migrate
```

Where `20121031XXXXXXXX` is the date stamp of the migration name. In other words, you'll have a migration named `20120410214815_some_relation.rb` (like) and you copy the date stamp from the filename and paste it into the command. Here's the [Rails Guide on Migrations for reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).